# How can I remove values from a data.frame based on logical values from another data.frame with matching indices?

Tags: r, dataframe

I know there's a way to do this with base R or dplyr or something similar but I just can't figure this out...

I have a data.frame, `p`, with data:

```
      TRIAL PCRIT_15min_fishMO2 PCRIT_15min_segmented PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2   PCRIT_25bins_segmented
3  Pcrit_3a              13.326                16.530               13.712                     NA
33 Pcrit_38               5.610                14.832                5.568                 15.091
50 Pcrit_59                  NA                    NA                4.421                  3.129
```

And a logical data.frame, `j`, with identical dimensions:

```
      TRIAL PCRIT_15min_fishMO2 PCRIT_15min_segmented PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2 PCRIT_25bins_segmented
3  Pcrit_3a               FALSE                 FALSE                FALSE                     NA
33 Pcrit_38               FALSE                 FALSE                FALSE                  FALSE
50 Pcrit_59                  NA                    NA                 TRUE                   TRUE
```

I want to remove values from `p` for which the equivalent value in `j` is `FALSE`. How can I do this?

My desired result is:

```
      TRIAL PCRIT_15min_fishMO2 PCRIT_15min_segmented PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2 PCRIT_25bins_segmented
3  Pcrit_3a                  NA                    NA                   NA                     NA
33 Pcrit_38                  NA                    NA                   NA                     NA
50 Pcrit_59                  NA                    NA                4.421                  3.129
```

Here's my data:

```
p = structure(list(TRIAL = c("Pcrit_3a", "Pcrit_38", "Pcrit_59"), 
PCRIT_15min_fishMO2 = c(13.326, 5.61, NA), PCRIT_15min_segmented = c(16.53, 
14.832, NA), PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2 = c(13.712, 5.568, 4.421
), PCRIT_25bins_segmented = c(NA, 15.091, 3.129)), .Names = c("TRIAL", 
"PCRIT_15min_fishMO2", "PCRIT_15min_segmented", "PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2", 
"PCRIT_25bins_segmented"), row.names = c(3L, 33L, 50L), class = "data.frame")

j = structure(list(TRIAL = c("Pcrit_3a", "Pcrit_38", "Pcrit_59"), 
PCRIT_15min_fishMO2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, NA), PCRIT_15min_segmented = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, NA), PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 
PCRIT_25bins_segmented = c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("TRIAL", 
"PCRIT_15min_fishMO2", "PCRIT_15min_segmented", "PCRIT_25bins_fishMO2", 
"PCRIT_25bins_segmented"), row.names = c(3L, 33L, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I would go with `is.na(p[-1]) <- !j[-1]` probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is

```
p[j == FALSE] <- NA
```

I am sure though that your question must have been answered in some form some place else in the forum though.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. That's what I would think but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @CephBirk Could be. Sometimes small ones slip through the net. ^_^ .

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do:

```
p[-1][!j[-1]] <- NA
```